# Python race condition with joining threads via all function

Tags: python, python-multithreading, race-condition, python-all-function

Please see the below code snippet, which fails to get past the first run locally with Python 3.10.

When I try to `join` all the threads within the built-in `all` function, always one of the threads is still alive.

What is the issue here, why is a race condition happening?

```py
import time
from threading import Thread

def expose_race_condition(run_index: int) -> None:
    threads: list[Thread] = [
        Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(1,)) for _ in range(10)
    ]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    # RACE CONDITION IS HERE
    assert not all(thread.join() for thread in threads)
    for thread_index, thread in enumerate(threads):
        # Uncommenting the below line defeats the race condition
        # assert not thread.join()
        assert (
            not thread.is_alive()
        ), f"Worker {thread_index} in run {run_index} was still alive."
    print(f"Completed run {run_index}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10_000):
        expose_race_condition(i)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do. This line, for example:

```py
   assert not all(thread.join() for thread in threads)
```

just doesn't make sense. `.join()` *always* returns `None`, so it's the same as

```py
   assert not all(None for thread in threads)
```

except that it has the side effect of joining threads. `all()` short-circuits the first time it sees a `False` value, which `None` is, so only the first `.join()` is actually called. `all(...)` returns `False`, so `not all(...)` returns `True`, so the `assert` succeeds. It's like:

```py
    threads[0].join()
    assert True
```

Short course: *any* code paying any attention to the value `thread.join()` returns is probably flat-out broken, because `None` is the only value it will ever see.

Comment: Wow... yes this is embarrassing.  Thank you @TimPeters for pointing out what is a rookie mistake, for some reason I thought `Thread.join` returned a `bool`.  And the `all`'s short-circuiting behavior... that makes sense.  Thank you again!